# How do I initialize a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP (less than a year), and to improve my development environment, I recently started using NetBeans IDE.

A warning keeps popping up everywhere stating that **"Variable might not have been initialized"**.

I'll give an example of a variable that results in this hint/warning:

```
$start = $per_page * $page;
```

**My question is: How can I initialize a PHP variable? Also, how important is it that a variable is initialized in PHP?**

I appreciate any advice you can provide.

*Note: I tried to place the following code above my variable, to no avail.*

```
$start = '';
```

Comment: The warning is suggesting that `$per_page` or `$page` might not have been initialized. You're initializing `$start` to the product of these variables, but were these two variables initialized?

Comment: Have you initialized `$per_page` and `$page`?

Comment: Are you sure Netbeans is referring to a PHP variable; I normally only see that error if I forget `var` when using JavaScript; you've not got a mix of PHP and JS in the document? `$start = '';` would initialise the variable... (unless it's in class scope but then you'd get a syntax error).

Comment: I see. @CD001 - No I don't have a mixture of PHP and JS in this document. @BoltClock, @Jonathan - I have not initialized `$per_page` or `$page`. I will try that. Is my syntax correct for initialization? e.g. `$per_page = '';`?

Comment: @CD001 - Thanks a bunch! Much appreciated. ALSO, anyone else noticing that Stack Overflow's image sprite isn't working correct? I'm not getting a lot of the up and down arrows to the left of questions and comments. I checked out the code, and it would seem that they are using a new version (v4) of the sprite which seems to be missing half of the images. Unless this is just my browser...

Comment: @CD001 - re the message being odd: the message isn't a PHP error; it's the IDE trying to be helpful and pointing out things which it thinks might cause a PHP error.

Comment: @Spudley - yes, I know, but I use Netbeans basically every day and I've _never_ seen that message refer to PHP ... which is why it seems a little odd (and why I asked if there was any JS in there) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$foo ='';
```

That’s how you initialize a variable. So you are correct.

```
$start = $per_page * $page;
```

For the above code, if one of the variables on the right side of the equation is not being initialized anywhere in the code, your IDE will complain thinking that they might be null. You might want to initialize them on separate lines to see if you will get the same warning.

Unlike for Java- and C#-like languages, in which you get lot of null pointer exceptions, the same thing doesn’t count for PHP. PHP is weakly-typed language, so you won't get any null pointer exceptions.

```
$start = $notinitiliazedvar;
```

This will basically have a default value.

```
<?php
class Foo{
    public $name;
    public $id;

    function __construct(){

    }

    public function toString(){
        return "{$this->name}, {$this->id}";
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->name = $test;

echo $f->name;

?>
```

You won't get any output with this code. So it’s OK. It’s just your IDE being paranoid.

```
$test = 1;
echo $test;
$test = "test";
echo $test;
```

Comment: Thanks. So what you're saying is that while it doesn't hurt to initialize my variables, it also isn't integral when using PHP?

Comment: You sould initialize the var s whatever type you are expecting not necessarily an empty string. In this cas i have to assume page and per page are going to be integers so i would use `0`, though `null` might also be acceptable if you want to check for initialization first.

Comment: well, you need to initialize what you need to initialize, php is very flexible language (weird IMO:)).

Comment: @stefmikhail: Its not integral. But it is good practice - depending on the error level you have set you will get warnings in your log.

Comment: @prodigitalson - I see, so if my variable will have an integer value, then initialize it as `0`, unless I need it be a different integer. And if the variable will have a string value, then use `''`?

Comment: look at my edit: php is a context sensitive language. there is no notion of strong typing. you can asssign a variable to a number and next like you can make it string.

Comment: @DarthVader - Ahh, I see. I appreciate the edit. I'm curious if you know much concerning variable types? I'm trying to use the type hinting in NetBeans, yet I'm a little confused when it comes to the list of types NetBeans gives you to choose from. Have a few moments for a chat?

Comment: i dont have few moments to chat, sorry but. i can say that IDE doesnt matter much. and netbeans is not that good of an IDE for php, IMO. Learn the semantics of php. and you ll be fine.

Comment: PHP only supports type hinting for Classes, Interfaces and Arrays. What Vader says is true... you can initalize a var as pretty much anything and cast it or convert it via an operation later. However, it is good practice to initialize them as the type you expect them to be or as `null` so an empty array is `$var = array()` string `$var = ''` integer `$var = 0` object `$var = null`. obviously you have leeway here depending on what your code actually does but this is generally how i like to do it.